# DDD + node.js: Where should domain logic go

Tags: node.js, mongodb, domain-driven-design

I am trying to institute DDD into a node.js application using es6.  I am using mongoose for my data access layer.  I noticed that mongoose has a ".methods" property tied to the model schema.  In terms of adding business logic to an entity, would this be an ideal place to add business logic or should I consider creating another object that holds the business logic that mirrors the model schema object and just copy the data from one to the other?  If I were using sequalize, what would be the preferred approach here?

Comment: There kind of persistence frameworks are much more effective for CRUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is really a definitive answer to this, but I'll give you some opinions.

A number of DDD *related* concepts and instruments are built around features exposed by OOP languages (in-particular: interfaces & IOC). In the JavaScript world, things tend to be a little different, particularly when leveraging the module system. That said, it's not impossible, but compromises might need to be made.

One of the more important points in DDD is that your models are "plain". They are completely ignorant of any persistence mechanisms, etc, they are simply just data and logic. By defining your models using Mongoose, you pretty much lose that; your business logic is being attached to a Mongoose schema object. But perhaps that is where you can compromise, it very much depends on how puristic you wish to be about it. Now, you can do mapping, as you suggested. If you do decide to go ahead with that idea, something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper) could help. I've been involved in a project that used ES7 decorators from [cerialize](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize) for a terser approach (we weren't using schemas, however).

Comment: That is my concern.  It seems like I would create coupling that could be a problem down the road if I needed to switch repositories, etc.  So, then, it would be a better approach to create a separate "entity" object that also contained the business rules and just move data back and forth using a mapper.  Thanks for the heads up.